# Commonality of Personality disorders

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience

Why is NPD are OCPD,BPD classfied as personality disorder? Especially for the last one.

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions - edit the original instead.  It is definitely an improvement, but this question still needs some work before it can be reopened, as it still contains multiple questions, unsourced claims, and unclear details.